# spring form controller with html checkbox

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to bind the input type checkbox using spring form controller,But i failed .

Here i am posting Controller,bean and jsp example,One more thing is i can't use 
 .

Below is the code:

Controller:

```
package com.test.web;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;

import com.vaannila.domain.User;
import com.vaannila.service.UserService;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class UserController extends SimpleFormController {

    private UserService userService;

    public UserController() {
        setCommandClass(User.class);
        setCommandName("user");
    }

    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws Exception {
        User user = (User) command;
        user.setCommunity(user.getCommunity());
        userService.add(user);
        return new ModelAndView("userForm","user",user);
    }

}
```

jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration Page</title>
<script>
function submitForm(){
document.testForm.submit();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form:form method="POST" commandName="user" name="testForm" action="./userRegistration.htm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password :</td>
            <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gender :</td>
            <td><form:radiobutton path="gender" value="M" label="M" /> 
                <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="F" label="F" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Country :</td>
            <td><form:select path="country">
                <form:option value="0" label="Select" />
                <form:option value="1" label="India" />
                <form:option value="2" label="USA" />
                <form:option value="3" label="UK" />
            </form:select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>About you :</td>
            <td><form:textarea path="aboutYou" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Community :</td>

                <td><input type="checkbox" name="community" value="Hibernate"/>Hibernate</br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="community" value="test"/>test</br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="community" value="test1"/>test1</br>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><form:checkbox path="mailingList"
                label="Would you like to join our mailinglist?" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" onclick="submitForm();"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Java beans:

```
package com.test.domain;

public class User {

    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String gender;
    private String country;
    private String aboutYou;
    private String[] community;
    private Boolean mailingList;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getAboutYou() {
        return aboutYou;
    }
    public void setAboutYou(String aboutYou) {
        this.aboutYou = aboutYou;
    }
    public String[] getCommunity() {
        return community;
    }
    public void setCommunity(String[] community) {
        this.community = community;
    }
    public Boolean getMailingList() {
        return mailingList;
    }
    public void setMailingList(Boolean mailingList) {
        this.mailingList = mailingList;
    }


}
```

I tried different ways,but no luck.Any hints please.

Comment: @ heldt :it doesn't give any exceptions or errors.It's not binding the value when i check the checkbox and submiting the form controller,I am submitting to the same page.Here i am loosing the checkbox.

Comment: you can check that. I just added the spring-mvc tag.

Answer (score 9):

the browser will not send the field in the request if the checkbox isn't checked. the value will either be "true" or not sent. you will never get a "false" value.

add a hidden field with _name for every checkbox

EX:
`<input type="checkbox" name="community" value="Hibernate"/>`
`<input type="hidden" name="_community" value="on"/>`

Then, spring will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use the form tag it will not automaticly bind your checkboxes. If you use plain html you have to bind the your self.

You can solve this by adding a list of community objects and then use form:checkboxes.
For example:

```
<form:checkboxes path="communityList" items="${communityList}" itemValue="key" itemLabel="value" />
```

I would also recomend you to use a HashMap when using ModelAndView like this:

```
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
model.put("user", user);
model.put("communityList", communityList);
return new ModelAndView("userFormat", model);
```

Manually bind using 'ServletRequestUtils'... http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/ServletRequestUtils.html

Example

```
public ModelAndView test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletRequestBindingException {
Long subscriptionOwnerId = ServletRequestUtils.getLongParameter(request, "id");
return new ModelAndView('test'); }`
```

Comment: yes iknow this,but unfortunately i can't use form:checkboxes.Because as per my requirement,based on one check box selection,i should populate other check boxes using ajax.In this i have to use input type=checkbox.How can i do manually bind this.